Get serverAuthCode using Credential Manager
We are updating our application to use the CredentialManager for logging in, but we are not finding a way to get the serverAuthCode from this new implementation. We need this information to maintain compatibility with our backend, which expects this information instead of the idToken.
Our old implementation:
val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(activityResult.data)
val account = try {
    task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
} catch (e: ApiException) {
    // Something treatment here
    null
}
val serverAuthCode = account?.serverAuthCode
// endpoint call

New implementation:
val googleIdOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder("our serverClientId").build()
val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
    .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
    .build()
val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)
val response = credentialManager.getCredential(context, request)
val credential = response.credential
if (credential is CustomCredential && credential.type == TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
    try {
        val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)
        // rest of the code and endpoint call

As I mentioned above, in this new implementation, it is not possible to get the serverAuthCode, only the idToken.
How should we go about getting the serverAuthCode and maintaining compatibility with our backend?
Here’s how I’m handling the authorization:
val authorizationLauncher = rememberAuthorizationLauncher()

val requestedScopes = listOf(
    Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME),
    Scope(Scopes.PROFILE),
    Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read"),
    Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read"),
    Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email")
)

val authorizationRequest = AuthorizationRequest.builder().setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes).build()

Identity.getAuthorizationClient(context)
    .authorize(authorizationRequest)
    .addOnSuccessListener { authorizationResult ->
        if (authorizationResult.hasResolution()) {
            authorizationResult.pendingIntent?.intentSender?.let { intentSender ->
            authorizationLauncher.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(intentSender).build())
            }
        } else {
            authorizationResult.serverAuthCode // always null
        }
    }

@Composable
private fun rememberAuthorizationLauncher(
    activity: Activity = LocalActivity.current
) = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
) { activityResult ->
    if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Identity.getAuthorizationClient(activity).getAuthorizationResultFromIntent(activityResult.data)
    }
}



The solution for this is to request offline access when building the authorization request:
AuthorizationRequest.builder()
    .setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes)
    .requestOfflineAccess(SERVER_CLIENT_ID) // THIS!
    .build()

See a working sample here

Thanks a lot, your example helped out a lot!

CredentialManager APIs allow you do "authentication". In order to get an auth code, you'd need to do authorization, for which you can use the Authorization APIs (which is not part of the CredentialManager).

First, I'm authenticating the user (using CredentialManager) and then requesting the authorization (using AuthorizationRequest), is that correct? Even so, I couldn't get the serverAuthCode, it is coming always as null.

To use the Authorization APIs, you don't need to Authenticate the user first; you can directly call the Authorization APIs, unless you really want to authenticate your users regardless. If the Authorization APIs are not working for you, please include code snippets of what you are doing.

We really need to perform the authentication first. So what I'm basically doing is calling the Credential Manager to authenticate, checking if everything worked fine, and then calling the Authorization API as added in the post.

That definitely works. Also, as a general comment, one main reason for us to separate authentication from authorization was to strongly encourage developers to ask for "authorization" in context; for example, in the old APIs, it was very common to include authentication and authorization together and that was presented at the very first "sign-in" page of the app; at that moment, users may not have the context on why this app is asking for, say, drive access. However, by separating the two, an app developer is encouraged to only ask for authorization... (to be continued )...

.. (continued)... when there is a need foe that, at the moment that it make sense to ask for that from a user; for example when a game wants to save the score in user's drive; it is more likely for users to accept such requests if they fully understand why it is being asked and how it wil be used.

Got it. However, to avoid changes to our backend, we need to send the server auth code, which is coming back as null when we make the authorization.
Our backend is using a similar implementation to this:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

If you need an auth code and are using th enew Authorization API and it returns null, then we need to dig in further to see what is happening. I suggest you file a bug and include (1) the relevant piece of code that you are using, and (2) a bug report so we can take a look

Hey @AliNaddaf, I created this project Login to show you how we are trying to log in. First, we call getCredential from the Credential Manager and then getAuthorizationClient from Authorization. In all cases, we have received null in the serverAuthCode, which is the information we need to pass to our backend.

What do you see on your screen when you run your code?

There is a button for signing in and then a message indicating the server auth code content. Could you run the app?

@AliNaddaf, what we need is pretty straightforward, in the deprecated docs we have an easy indication on how to request a server auth code: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount Our question is simple: Where can we find in the docs a sample of how to do the same with the new APIs, when we follow the links on the old docs, it takes us to some new implementation that has NO REFERENCE to how to get this server auth code whatsoever. For instance this: https://developers.google.com/identity/authorization/android

Nevermind just went through the docs pages and found the solution, posted as an answer below...

@AliNaddaf, but how it's possible to specify scope? In some cases the idToken returned from GetSignInWithGoogleOption is missing some data, "email" is one of them.

Specify scopes where, which API are you using?
